# Getting GPS mobile location data in CakePHP 3

Tags: android, cakephp, gps, cakephp-3.0

Am working on a rural farmers registration application and would like to capture location of a farm. Please help with any ideas on how I can achieve this.

Basically, I need the user to press a button to get their GPS Coordinates and save it in MySQL.

I have checked out the `Dereuromark/CakePHP-geo` plugin on GitHub, but that doesn't seem to even try to achieve this.

Comment: Use browser location services? Or a map with a draggable marker?

Comment: Thanks @halfer. I'd like to enhance my solution by provide the suggested Marker option. This can make a simple CakePHP Plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to **Bogdan Romulus** and **Ruben Alzate Quintero** on the Google+ CakePHP Community. I started following on the the suggestions to use the inbuilt HTML 5 geolocation feature as suggested by **halfer**.

Here's my solution:
1. Create a defered block level javascript

```
     echo $this->Html->script('gps', [
       'block' => true,
       'defer' => true
     ]);
```

2. Set "id" to my intended Form fields

```
     echo $this->Form->input('gps', [
        'label' => 'GPS Coordinates',
        'id' => 'gps',
        'required' => false
    ]);
```

3. In my gps.js script linked in step 1

```
     var g = document.getElementById("gps");

     window.onload = function() {
         if (navigator.geolocation) {
             navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setPosition);
         } else {
             //x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
         }
      }

      function setPosition(position) {
         g.value = position.coords.latitude + ', ' + position.coords.longitude;

      }
```

This is not a perfect answer but its a start towards that :). Some helpful links I used along the way:

1. http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html#linking-to-javascript-files
2. http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html5_geolocation.asp

Comment: OK, great. You could also look into leaflet.js to add draggable markers - it works with a variety of map providers (I use it with OpenStreetMap).

Comment: (Aside: please don't add commentary to posts about how people have voted or how they should vote or any other meta topic. Put it in comments if you must, but otherwise don't worry about it. Posts should just contain information useful to future readers - complaints about votes aren't useful to people in a year's time!).

Comment: Thanks @halfer (for the tip too), i'll post a link to any further developments on this.